# Reading RGB values from TIFF Image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, rgb, geotiff

I have a tiff Image and I am reading the RGB values of each pixel with following code. the Image Height :16198 width :12900.

But the code is taking much longer time (more than 20 minutes). tried various way like converting it to bitmap, but non of them leads to better performance. any suggestions

```
            using (Tiff tiffreader = Tiff.Open(imgpath, "r"))
            {
                img.Width = tiffreader.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
                img.Height = tiffreader.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
                img.DipX = tiffreader.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION)[0].ToInt();
                img.DipY = tiffreader.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION)[0].ToInt();

                // Reading RGB values
                int height = (int)img.Height;
                int width = (int)img.Width;
                int[] raster = new int[height*width];

                var b =  tiffreader.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster);

                img.Pixels = new PColor[height, width];
                img.Pixels = Utility.ConvertToRGB(height, width, raster);
            }


     internal static PColor[,] ConvertToRGB(int height, int width, int[] raster)
    {
        PColor[,] pcolor = new PColor[height, width];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                {
                    int offset = (height - j - 1) * width + i;
                    PColor color = new PColor();
                    color.R = Tiff.GetR(raster[offset]);
                    color.G = Tiff.GetG(raster[offset]);
                    color.B = Tiff.GetB(raster[offset]);

                    pcolor[i, j] = color;
                }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }

        return pcolor;
    }
```

Comment: Can you read it into a Bitmap? You can use Lockbits for fast access to it. What do you want to do with the pixels??

Comment: I tried with Bitmap, no performance improvement, I want to use this RGB values for region growing further around some seed points.

Comment: The key is not Bitmap but Lockbits. Did you use that? But reading such a huge file into one Bitmap is itself probably too much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing unnecessary processing of the file. The whole loop that calls **ReadScanline** seems to be pointless since you just read the whole file later with a call to **ReadRGBAImage**. I'm not sure what class backs the **img** variable, but it looks like it has duplicated data in it (The **Pixels** property and the **bytearray** variable). I would see if you can refactor your code to remove one of these items.

It would also be good to change your loops to convert to RGB to have **i** (the height) be the inside loop so that you are accessing the raster array in order (which saves a lot of memory fetches).

Also note that 2-dimensional array access is significantly slower than 1d because of double bounds checking. In my own experience it's actually faster to calculate the offset of a 1d array manually than to use a C# 2d array. It might be worth refactoring **Pixels** to be 1d.

EDIT: If you can't refactor the code to remove **Pixels** or **bytearray**, then I would suggest creating the **bytearray** variable contents from the contents of **raster** instead of re-reading the file again.